# highlightSeries plugin for jquery flot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm looking for help with the highlightSeries plugin made by Brian Peiris (http://brian.peiris.name/highlightSeries/). It doesn't appear to be working; I'm positive that the event is firing, because an alert test I performed earlier worked just fine, printing out `$(this).text()`. I'm trying to get the series on the chart to be highlighted when the user mouses over the series name in the legend (something which works perfectly fine on Mr. Peiris's website).

```
   $('.server-chart').each(function() {
        var serv = $(this).attr('id').substr(6);
        var plotData = [];
        //alert(serv + ": " + $.toJSON(serverStats[serv]));
        for (var k in serverStats[serv].StatsByCollection) {
            var outlabel = k;
            var outdata = serverStats[serv].StatsByCollection[k];
            plotData.push({ label: outlabel, data: outdata});
        }
        plotOptions = {
            legend: {
                container: $('#legend-' + serv),
                labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
                    return '<a href="#' + label + '" class="checked label-clickable">' + label + '</a>';
                },
                noColumns: 2
            },
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    fill: false
                },
                points: {
                    show: false,
                    fill: false
                }
            },
            colors: colors,
            grid: {
                hoverable: false
            },
            highlightSeries: {
                color: "#FF00FF"
    }
        }
        $_plot = $.plot(this, plotData, plotOptions);
        $plots.push($_plot);
        $('#legend-' + serv + ' .legendLabel, #legend-' + serv + ' .legendColorBox').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $_plot.highlightSeries($(this).text());
        });
        $('#legend-' + serv + ' .legendLabel, #legend-' + serv + ' .legendColorBox').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $_plot.unHighlightSeries($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure what other code to put on here, so tell me if you need more; the charts are all working fine, this is just the part of the ready function setting up all of the plots and their options inside the placeholders.

Also, there's a couple of classes attached to the labels that are extraneous; I was trying different things to get this stuff to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin requires a patched version of `flot` to work (it introduces a public `drawSeries` method).  [The last patched version](https://github.com/brianpeiris/highlightSeries/blob/master/jquery.flot.js) is for an older version of flot (0.7).

With that said, I wouldn't use this plugin.  If you just want to highlight a series on legend mouseover it's pretty simple.

```
$('#legend .legendLabel, #legend .legendColorBox').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var label = $(this).text();
    var allSeries = $_plot.getData();
    // find your series by label
    for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++){
      if (allSeries[i].label == label){
        allSeries[i].oldColor = allSeries[i].color;
        allSeries[i].color = 'black'; // highlight it in some color
        break;
      }
    }
    $_plot.draw(); // draw it
  });

  $('#legend .legendLabel, #legend .legendColorBox').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var label = $(this).text();
    var allSeries = $_plot.getData();
    for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++){
      if (allSeries[i].label == label){
        allSeries[i].color = allSeries[i].oldColor;
        break;
      }
    }
    $_plot.draw();
  });
```

See example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9xmZQSXcG6H7cwwp72J?p=preview).

Comment: I actually figured it out, it was due to a strange issue involving the $_plot variable; basically, the right plot object wasn't being selected. I have an array of all the plots created on the page, so I just added a "serverName" property to the plots as they were generated, and matched up the server names (serv variable) to the plot, which solved the problem. 
Thanks for the implementation though, I'll accept your answer for that.